# Decode cyrillic quoted-printable content

Tags: c#, imap, decode

I'm using [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-IMAP-CLIENT-b249d2e6) sample for getting mail from server. Problem is that response contains cyrillic symbols I cannot decode.
Here is a header:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset="koi8-r"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

And receive response function:

```
static void receiveResponse(string command)
{
    try
    {
        if (command != "")
        {
            if (tcpc.Connected)
            {
                dummy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
                ssl.Write(dummy, 0, dummy.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("TCP CONNECTION DISCONNECTED");
            }
        }
        ssl.Flush();

        byte[] bigBuffer = new byte[1024*16];
        int bites = ssl.Read(bigBuffer, 0, bigBuffer.Length);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bites];
        Array.Copy(bigBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, bites);

        sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));

        string result = sb.ToString();

        // here is an unsuccessful attempt at decoding
        result = Regex.Replace(result, @"=([0-9a-fA-F]{2})",
            m => m.Groups[1].Success
            ? Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value, 16)).ToString()
            : "");

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(result);
        result = Encoding.GetEncoding("koi8r").GetString(bytes);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

How to decode stream correctly? In result string I got `<p>=F0=D2=C9=D7=C5=D4 =D1 =F7=C1=CE=D1</p>` instead of `<p>Привет я Ваня</p>`.

Comment: Do the quoted printable decoding.

Comment: @Max yes, but problem is how to inplement correct quoted printable decoding

Comment: Which data `result` variable holds before you call `result = Regex.Replace(result, @"=([0-9a-fA-F]{2})", ...`? Please update your answer with the message data that you receive from mail server (hex bytes).

Comment: @CodeFuller sorry, updated..

Comment: What is the value of `result` after `string result = sb.ToString();` executed?

Comment: @CodeFuller this is string with message body formatted as html.

Comment: The easiest way of course is to use a library, however, you need to deal with it at the byte level, because QP are bytes, not characters.  Do not convert to string in the meantime.  Do you have byte regex functions available to you?

Comment: @Max do you mean that I have to decode data before converting to string here: `string result = sb.ToString()` ?

Comment: @Max no, I have no such functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Max pointed out, you will need to decode the content using the encoding algorithm declared in the Content-Transfer-Encoding header.

In your case, it is the [quoted-printable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding.

You will need to decode the text of the message into an array of bytes and then you’ll need to convert that array of bytes into a string using the appropriate System.Text.Encoding. The name of the encoding to use will typically be specified in the Content-Type header as the charset parameter (in your case, koi8-r).

Since you already have the text as bytes in the buffer variable, simply perform the deciding on that:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[bites];
int decodedLength = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < bites; i++) {
    if (bigBuffer[i] == (byte) '=') {
        if (bites > i + 1) {
            // possible hex sequence
            byte b1 = bigBuffer[i + 1];
            byte b2 = bigBuffer[i + 2];

            if (IsXDigit (b1) && IsXDigit (b2)) {
                // decode
                buffer[decodedLength++] = (ToXDigit (b1) << 4) | ToXDigit (b2);
                i += 2;
            } else if (b1 == (byte) '\r' && b2 == (byte) '\n') {
                // folded line, drop the '=\r\n' sequence
                i += 2;
            } else {
                // error condition, just pass it through
                buffer[decodedLength++] = bigBuffer[i];
            }
        } else {
            // truncated? just pass it through
            buffer[decodedLength++] = bigBuffer[i];
        }
    } else {
        buffer[decodedLength++] = bigBuffer[i];
    }
}

string result = Encoding.GetEncoding ("koi8-r").GetString (buffer, 0, decodedLength);
```

Custom functions:

```
static byte ToXDigit (byte c)
{
    if (c >= 0x41) {
        if (c >= 0x61)
            return (byte) (c - (0x61 - 0x0a));

        return (byte) (c - (0x41 - 0x0A));
    }

    return (byte) (c - 0x30);
}

static bool IsXDigit (byte c)
{
    return (c >= (byte) 'A' && c <= (byte) 'F') || (c >= (byte) 'a' && c <= (byte) 'f') || (c >= (byte) '0' && c <= (byte) '9');
}
```

Of course, instead of writing your own hodge podge IMAP library, you could just use [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) and [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) ;-)

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte' at line `buffer[decodedLength++] = (ToXDigit (b1) << 4) | ToXDigit (b2);`

Comment: `buffer[decodedLength++] = (byte)((ToXDigit (b1) << 4) | ToXDigit (b2))` is works but decoding is not correct